# Complex symmetric matrix $A$ -- relationship between $AA^*$ and $A^*A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, unitary-matrices

I've been working on this problem for a while, and haven't been able to figure out where to start from. The problem is:

Let $A$ be a complex symmetric matrix. What is the relationship between $AA^*$ and $A^*A$? Prove your claim.

I've tried using $A = A^T$ and $A^* = \overline{A}^T$ and plugging these definitions into $AA^*$ and $A^*A$, but that hasn't gotten me anywhere significant. Any tips / suggestions / solutions?

Comment: I guess it depends on what sort of relationship you're looking for... For example, $(A A^*)^T = (A^*)^T A^T = \overline{A} A = \overline{A \overline{A}}$, and when you do the same for $A^* A$ you get..?

Comment: $(A^*A)^T = (A^T)(\overline{A}^T)^T) = (A^T)(\overline{A})$ is what I get...how did you get from the 3rd to 4th steps in your work? Also, I am assuming that they are equal?

Comment: And in your last step, what is $A^T$? (Keep in mind the assumptions.) From my third to fourth step: just note that $\overline{\overline{A}} = A$.

Comment: $A^T$ is just $A$, beecause $A$ is complex symmetric. And, could you please elaborate a bit more on $\overline{\overline{A}} = A$ being used in your work? I don't get how we get $\overline{A}A = \overline{A\overline{A}}$.

Comment: Try it with just a complex number or two, to convince yourself. If $z = a + b i$, then what is $\overline{z}$, and what's the conjugate of *that*? Then try the same with, say, $(a + b i)\overline{(c + d i)}$ and try taking the conjugate of that product.

Comment: Ohhh, I now know what you meant...so, after we use that last step, with $A^*A$, we should see that $AA^* = A^*A$, right?

Comment: Also, why did you take the transpose of $AA^*$ in the first problem. How can I show that they are equal with this? Do I show $(AA^*)^T = (A^*A)^T$?

Comment: No, not quite $A A^* = A^* A$, but close. As to why taking transpose in the first place: just a hunch, since $^*$ is related to transpose, transposes play nice with products, and we were told $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: I see. After expanding both $(AA^*)^T$ and $(A^*A)^T$, I get $\overline{A^*A}$ and $\overline{AA^*}$, respectively. I don't see how this simplifies the original problem, however, since we're now just comparing the complex conjugates of $AA^*$ and $A^*A$...any advice from here? Thanks a lot for your help, by the way!

Comment: Right, so what you've found out is that if you transpose $A A^*$, you get the conjugate of $A^* A$. So (moving the transpose to the other side), we have $A A^* = (A^* A)^*$.

Comment: Ahhh, I see, thank you so much for your help. Your guidance / steps were tremendously helpful!

Comment: There's a typo in my last comment---sorry about that. I fixed it in the answer below.

Comment: Got it -- thanks so much (again)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since transpose is related to $^*$, plays well with products, and we're told $A$ is symmetric, it seems sensible to try taking transposes.
In doing so,
$$ (A A^*)^T = (A \overline{A}^T)^T = \overline{A} A^T = \overline{A} A, $$
and similarly
$$ (A^* A)^T = (\overline{A}^T A)^T = A^T \overline{A} = A \overline{A}. $$
These are conjugates of one another, so we see that
$$ \overline{(A A^*)^T} = (A^* A)^T, $$
or in other words
$$ (A A^*)^* = (A^* A)^T. $$